# Make order notes required for specific product categories in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, taxonomy-terms

I need to make order notes required only on certain product categories (eg if someone buys "cards", they have to fill in a message).

I've found this snippet to make order notes required, I just need to set it to be associated with a certain product.

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
     return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will make checkout order notes field required for specific product(s) category(ies):

```
// Conditional function that check for specific product(s) category(ies)
function is_product_category_terms_in_cart( $categories ) {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Make order notes required field conditionally
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'make_order_notes_required_field' );
function make_order_notes_required_field( $fields ) {
    // Set in the array your targeted product category term(s)
    $categories = array("cards");

    if ( is_product_category_terms_in_cart( $categories ) ) {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.